# generic view does not return any values

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views

I am a beginner in django, and its version is `1.11.6` ,as well as the python version I use is `3.6`.
I am studying generic view, `generic.ListView`does not return any values.

```
views.py


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'Latest_question_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$',views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

the output of above code is:

> no polls are available

the html page is included the following code:

```
    {% if latest_question_list %}


    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
<p>no polls are available</p>
{% endif %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}"/>
```

unfortunately, I could not get the reason of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have `context_object_name = 'Latest_question_list'` (with a capital L) in your view, which does not match `{% if latest_question_list %}` (all lowercase) in your template.

Change either the view or template so that they match. The PEP 8 style guide would recommend `latest_question_list`, so I would change the view:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'
```